# How to clone two columns in a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, clone

I am trying to clone 2 columns from a table to a new table using jQuery.
The source table is below:

```
<table id="sourceT">
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1 - value</td>
        <td>Col 2 - value</td>
        <td>Col 3 - value</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="targetT"></table>
```

What I tried is,

```
$("#sourceT").find("tr > td:nth-child(1), tr > td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {
    $("#targetT").append($("<tr></tr>").append($(this).clone()));
});
```

I only want to copy first and second columns to a new table like

```
<table id="targetT">
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1 - value</td>
        <td>Col 2 - value</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

But using those jquery, I only get like below;

```
<table id="targetT">
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
    </td>
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1 - value</td>
    </td>
    <tr>
        <td>Col 2</td>
    </td>
    <tr>
        <td>Col 2 - value</td>
    </td>
</table>
```

I am not trying to loop all the tr and td's from source table. Coz, my source table is going to be more than thousands rows and more than 50 cols.
Anyone has got any ideas?

Comment: I have understood that I cannot select only n columns out of a table. I have 2 options, that I have to loop rows and filter the columns I need OR I need to copy the whole table and get rid of columns that I don't need. Am I right?

Comment: http://jsperf.com/cloning-and-append-rows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
var $target = $("#targetT");
$("#sourceT tr").each(function() {
    var $tds = $(this).children(),
        $row = $("<tr></tr>");
    $row.append($tds.eq(0).clone()).append($tds.eq(1).clone()).appendTo($target);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HwzQg/

That is, loop through each row of the source table and just copy the required columns. This way it doesn't matter if the required columns are adjacent, and it is easy to change the code to copy more columns if your requirement changes. In fact you could easily encapsulate it in a function that takes the source and target tables as parameters along with a list of which column numbers to copy:

```
function copyColumns(srcTableId, targetTableId) {
    var colNos = [].slice.call(arguments,2),
        $target = $("#" + targetTableId);
    $("#" + srcTableId + " tr").each(function() {
        var $tds = $(this).children(),
            $row = $("<tr></tr>");
        for (var i = 0; i < colNos.length; i++)
            $row.append($tds.eq(colNos[i]).clone());
        $row.appendTo($target);
    });
}

copyColumns("sourceT", "targetT", 0, 1);
// NOTE that this allows you to easily re-order the columns as you copy them:
copyColumns("sourceT", "targetT", 1, 0, 2);
```

This uses `arguments` to let you have any number of column numbers as separate arguments, but of course you could modify it to instead accept an array of column numbers. Whatever works for you.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HwzQg/1/

> *"I am not trying to loop all the tr and td's from source table. Coz, my source table is going to be more than thousands rows and more than 50 cols."*

I wouldn't worry about the size of the source table. Code to get the result you need first, and then optimise the code if the performance is poor. The code you showed is kind of implicitly looping through the original table twice anyway with `td:nth-child(1)` and then `td:nth-child(2)`.

Comment: I also created a function to do this based on your initial answer. I see you had the same idea. http://jsfiddle.net/5MQJV/

Comment: Thanks @mrtsherman. Joshua: you are welcome - I realise the other answers provide ways to do this with less code, but I was trying to illustrate a more versatile way of tackling the problem in case your requirements varied.

Comment: @nnnnnn well..I don't really care whether the code is long or short. But I really care is about the performance. I am building an fixed table with rows and cols. That's why I care about the performance. And your code is so great, too.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
$("#sourceT tr").each(function(index) {
    var newRow = $("<tr></tr>");
    $(this).find("td:lt(2)").each(function() {
        newRow.append($(this).clone());
    })
    $("#targetT").append(newRow);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JRwVN/

Or an even more compact version that uses more chaining instead of the `.each()`:

```
$("#sourceT tr").each(function(index) {
    var newRow = $("<tr></tr>");
    $(this).find("td:lt(2)").clone().appendTo(newRow);
    $("#targetT").append(newRow);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QRVfE/

Any code, regardless of selectors, that finds the columns you want is going to look in every row of the table.  Walking the DOM (which is what these selector operations do) is not a slow operation.  What is a slow operation is creating new DOM objects and inserting them in the DOM and there's no way to avoid that in your case.

If performance was super critical (something you should prove is actually a problem before attacking it), there are actually times when it's faster to create a giant HTML string and put that into the DOM all at once rather than inserting individual DOM objects.

If performance was critical, a version that constructs an HTML string seems to be about 20% faster in Chrome, IE10 and Firefox.  It works like this:

```
var newTable = "";
$("#sourceT tr").each(function(index) {
    newTable += "<tr>";
    $(this).find("td:lt(2)").each(function() {
        newTable += "<td>" + this.innerHTML + "</td>";
    });
    newTable += "</tr>";
});
$("#targetT").html(newTable);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/MDAKe/

And, the jsperf that compares the last two ways: http://jsperf.com/table-copy

I'm sure there are other ways to improve performance (usually jQuery itself doesn't give you the fastest running code).

---

As it turns out, removing all jQuery makes it about 8-12x faster (depending upon browser):

```
var newTable = "";
var rows = document.getElementById("sourceT").rows;
for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].cells;
    newTable += "<tr><td>" + cells[0].innerHTML + "</td><td>" + cells[1].innerHTML + "</td></tr>";
}
document.getElementById("targetT").innerHTML = newTable;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7AJk2/

Comment: @undefined - Thx.  I incorporated that into the second version.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer jfriend00.

Comment: Added several much faster options.  Removing the jQuery made it the fastest.

Comment: @JoshuaSon - if you really care about performance, then check out the last option here in my answer (8-12x faster than the previous options) with a jsPerf to compare the various choices.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thx I will have a look.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I am too get used to jquery, coz I am afraid of cross-browsers. http://jsperf.com/cloning-and-append-rows/2

Comment: @JoshuaSon - look at [my jsperf](http://jsperf.com/table-copy).  I think you have to clean up the DOM (like I do in my jsperf) before each test to make it a fair test.

Comment: is there a difference between using array and string? I think I can clean up the newTable by newTable  = ""; at the end. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JoshuaSon - the array version in my jsperf is not faster than using a string.  Years ago, it probably would have been, but strings have been sped up a lot.  In the jsperf, you have to actually clean up the stuff that's insert in the DOM before each test.  The jsperf has a place to do that. It's the box called "Define setup for all tests".  You can see how I did it in mine.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#sourceT tr').clone().appendTo('#targetT')
$('#targetT tr').find('td :gt(1)').remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QxFDL/)

OR

```
var clone = $('#sourceT tr').clone()
clone.find('td :gt(1)').remove();
clone.appendTo('#targetT')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QxFDL/1/)

I may prefer the OR portion since the dom is updated only once

Comment: Thanks Arun. I got what you mean. But if I have to copy only 2 columns out of 50 columns, then I have to remove all the 48 columns? Are there any efficient ways?

Comment: you mean the last two columns

Comment: Nop, they are going to be first 2 columns always. Or they might be first 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sourceT tr')
        .clone()
        .find('td:gt(1)')
        .remove()
        .end()
        .appendTo('#targetT');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C7dKF/

Answer (score -1):

I have goog way, how to play with columns, i write here full code:

```js
function add_column(copy, paste)
{
  $("."+copy+":first").clone().appendTo("."+paste);
  $("."+paste+" tr:last input").val('');
  $("."+paste+" tr:last select").val('');
  // and etc...
}

function remove_column(e, paste)
{
  var how = $("."+paste+" tr").length;
  if(how >= 2)
  {
    $(e).parent().parent().remove();
  } else {
    $("."+paste+" input").val('');
    $("."+paste+" select").val('');
    // and etc...
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="atostogos">
          <div class="panel-body">

           <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
           <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
             <thead>
              <tr>
               <th width="30%">Priežastis</th>
               <th width="15%">Data nuo</th>
               <th width="15%">Data iki</th>
               <th width="30%">Pastabos</th>
               <th width="10%">Veiksmai</th>
              </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody class="paste_place">
               <tr class="copy_item">
                 <td><input type="text" name="priezastis[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Įveskite..."/></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="data_nuo[]" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Įveskite..."/></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="data_iki[]" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Įveskite..."/></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="pastabos[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Įveskite..."/></td>
                 <td><a onclick="add_column('copy_item', 'paste_place');"><i style="font-size: 20px;" class="icon-plus-circle2"></i></a> &nbsp;<a onclick="remove_column(this, 'paste_place');"><i style="font-size: 20px; color: red;" class="icon-minus-circle2"></i></a></td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

          <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="text-right">
               <button name="holidays_info" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Išsaugoti <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </form>

          </div>
         </div>
```